# Google earth problem

Tags: javascript, geospatial, google-earth-plugin

I want to use Google Earth for a presentation. I want to start with rotating the globe, and after a while zoom in to a certain location. The rotating stuff works, but somehow the zoom doesn't. I have the following code

```
var ge;
google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('map', initCB, failureCB);
}

function initCB(instance) {
  ge = instance;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
  ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_HIDE);

  var oldFlyToSpeed = ge.getOptions().getFlyToSpeed();
  ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(ge.SPEED_TELEPORT);
}

var moveCamera = function(count) {
  var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
  lookAt.setLatitude(lookAt.getLatitude() + .1);
  lookAt.setLongitude(lookAt.getLongitude() + 5);
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);

  if (count &lt; 215) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    moveCamera(count + 1);
    }, 150);
  } else {
    ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(oldFlyToSpeed);
    loadRoute();
  }
}

var loadRoute = function(){
  ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(0.1); 
  var la = ge.createLookAt('');
  la.set(12, -84, 5000, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 0, 0, 750000);
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);
}

moveCamera(0);
document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML = ge.getPluginVersion();

function failureCB(errorCode){}
```

I know the peace of code in `loadRoute();` works, because i tested that before.

Does anybody know what goes wrong here?

Comment: @Fraser: You might want to explain the edits you made, especially if they fix the problem. :)

Comment: why `<` got changed to `&lt;`, btw?

Comment: not sure, think it is because you used the <code> tag and I used indenting. I think you must have entered &lt; when you posted, no?

Answer (score 0):

Your code had multiple errors, namely the loadroute function was part of the moveCamera function due to a missing closing brace. I have edited it in your post so hopefully that should work.